# about proof of theorem in the nonsingular Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing

in the Algebraic Geometry by Robin Hartshorne we have :

Lemma 6.4. Let $Y$ be a quasi-projective variety, let $P, Q \in Y,$ and suppose that $\mathcal{O}_{Q} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{P}$ as subrings of $K(Y) .$ Then $P=Q$

ProoF. Embed $Y$ in $\mathbf{P}^{n}$ for some $n .$ Replacing $Y$ by its closure, we may assume $Y$ is projective. After a suitable linear change of coordinates in $\mathbf{P}^{n}$ we may assume that neither $P$ nor $Q$ is in the hyperplane $H_{0}$ defined by $x_{0}=0 .$ Thus $P, Q \in Y \cap\left(\mathbf{P}^{n}-H_{0}\right)$ which is affine, so we may assume that $Y$ is an affine variety.

Let $A$ be the affine ring of $Y .$ Then there are maximal ideals $\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{n} \subseteq A$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{P}=A_{\mathrm{m}}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{Q}=A_{\mathrm{n}} .$ If $\mathcal{O}_{Q} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{P},$ we must have $\mathrm{m} \subseteq \mathrm{n} .$ But
$\mathrm{m}$ is a maximal ideal, so $\mathrm{m}=\mathrm{n}$, hence $P=Q$, by $(3.2 \mathrm{~b})$

> what is mean of  "Embed" in the above theorem ? why we can  Replacing $Y$ by its closure and why  we may assume $Y$ is projective ? Can this theorem be proved in a  simpler way? why  there are maximal ideals $\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{n} \subseteq A$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{P}=A_{\mathrm{m}}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{Q}=A_{\mathrm{n}}$ ?
> what is $A_{\mathrm{m}}$ and $A_{\mathrm{n}}$ ? what is definition of affine ring ?

Comment: By 'embed' they mean take an immersion into $\mathbb{P}^n$, which exists because $Y$ is quasiprojective. Regarding the assumption that $Y$ is projective: since $\mathcal{O}_P$ and $\mathcal{O}_Q$ are local rings, only local information is relevant.

Comment: If $Y$ is affine then you can write $Y = \operatorname{Spec} A$. Closed points of $Y$ are in correspondence with maximal ideals of $A$, and their local rings are localisations of $A$ at this maximal ideal, which is what is denoted $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer . Closed points is same as limit points ?

Comment: A closed point is a point closed with respect to the topology, but if you haven't seen schemes yet then you can ignore that part. In that case, what you should think is the following: If I have $\mathbb{A}^n$ and I pick a point with coordinates $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$, then the local ring at this point is the localisation of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ at the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = (x_1 - a_1,\ldots,x_n - a_n)$.